In Nest.js, how to tap into lifecyle events from durable providers to release db connections
I have created a durable provider to return a db connection for a given tenant. The provider will also keep a local cache of connections to reuse. As request-scoped providers cannot tap into application lifecycle events, I don't have a way to trigger closing the connections when app.close() is triggered. In my example below, onModuleDestroy will never be called, which results in Jest warnings like

Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

Would love to here how others have dealt with this.
Example of the TenancyService below:
import { Inject, Injectable, OnModuleDestroy, Scope } from '@nestjs/common'
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core'
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm'
import { tenantedConfig } from '@/orm.config'
import { TenantService } from '@/modules/public/tenants/tenant.service'

interface ContextPayload {
  tenantId?: string
}

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST, durable: true })
export class TenancyService implements OnModuleDestroy {
  private tenantConnections: { [schemaName: string]: DataSource } = {}
  private readonly tenantId: string

  constructor(
    private readonly tenantService: TenantService,
    @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly requestContext: ContextPayload
  ) {
    console.info(this.requestContext)
    this.tenantId = this.requestContext.tenantId
  }

  async getDataSource(): Promise<DataSource> {
    if (this.tenantConnections[this.tenantId] == null) {
      const { schema } = await this.tenantService.findOneByTenant(this.tenantId)

      const dataSource = new DataSource({
        ...tenantedConfig,
        schema
      } as DataSourceOptions)

      try {
        await dataSource.initialize()
      } catch (error: unknown) {
        console.error('Failed to initialize tenant connection', error)
        throw error
      }

      this.tenantConnections[this.tenantId] = dataSource
    }

    return this.tenantConnections[this.tenantId]
  }

  async onModuleDestroy() {
    await Promise.all(
      Object.values(this.tenantConnections).map((dataSource) =>
        dataSource.destroy()
      )
    )
    console.debug('Tenant connections destroyed')
  }
}


The solution was injecting a singleton provider that manages the connection cache into the request-scoped durable provider.
For example:
import { FactoryProvider, Global, Module, Scope } from '@nestjs/common'
import { TenantsModule } from '@/modules/public/tenants/tenants.module'
import { CONNECTION, ContextPayload } from '@/modules/tenancy/types'
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm'
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core'
import { TenancyConnectionService } from '@/modules/tenancy/tenancy-connection.service'

const dataSourceProvider: FactoryProvider<DataSource> = {
  provide: CONNECTION,
  scope: Scope.REQUEST,
  durable: true,
  useFactory: (
    contextPayload: ContextPayload,
    tenancyConnectionService: TenancyConnectionService
  ) => {
    return tenancyConnectionService.getConnection(contextPayload.tenantId)
  },
  inject: [REQUEST, TenancyConnectionService]
}

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [TenantsModule],
  providers: [dataSourceProvider, TenancyConnectionService],
  exports: [CONNECTION]
})
export class TenancyModule {}


import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm'
import { tenantedConfig } from '@/orm.config'
import { TenantsService } from '@/modules/public/tenants/tenants.service'
import { Injectable, OnModuleDestroy } from '@nestjs/common'

@Injectable()
export class TenancyConnectionService implements OnModuleDestroy {
  private readonly tenantConnections = new Map<string, DataSource>()

  constructor(private readonly tenantService: TenantsService) {}

  async getConnection(tenantId: string): Promise<DataSource> {
    if (!this.tenantConnections.has(tenantId)) {
      const { schema } = await this.tenantService.findOneByTenant(tenantId)

      const dataSource = new DataSource({
        ...tenantedConfig,
        schema
      } as DataSourceOptions)

      try {
        await dataSource.initialize()
      } catch (error: unknown) {
        console.error('Failed to initialize tenant connection', error)
        throw error
      }

      this.tenantConnections.set(tenantId, dataSource)
    }

    return this.tenantConnections.get(tenantId)
  }

  async onModuleDestroy() {
    console.debug('Tenant connections destroyed')
    await Promise.all(
      [...this.tenantConnections.values()].map((dataSource) =>
        dataSource.destroy()
      )
    )
    console.debug('Tenant connections destroyed')
  }
}

Import into your relevant service:
@Injectable()
export class CharactersService {
  private readonly characterRepository: Repository<Character>

  constructor(@Inject(CONNECTION) private readonly connection: DataSource) {
    this.characterRepository = this.connection.getRepository(Character)
  }

  async findAll() {
    return this.characterRepository.find()
  }

  async create(createCharacterDto: CreateCharacterDto) {
    return this.characterRepository.save(
      this.characterRepository.create(createCharacterDto)
    )
  }
}

